Derivative on a product of independent functions
If I have three (vector)functions, al dependent on different (complex)variables:
\begin{equation}
a = X^{\mu_1}(z_1, \bar{z}_1), 
b = X^{\mu_2}(z_2, \bar{z}_2), 
c= X^{\mu_3}(z_3, \bar{z}_3)
\end{equation}
I am interested in the consecutive derivative with respect to $z_1$, and $\bar{z}\_1$ (I write $\partial_1$ meaning $\partial_{z_1}$, likewise for the conjugate). And I also have some relation for $\partial_{1}\bar{\partial}_{1}(ab)$, $\partial_{1}\bar{\partial}_{1}(ac)$ which I want to single out. Using the product rule and that functions $b$ and $c$ are independent of $z_1, \bar{z}\_1$ I get:
\begin{equation}
\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(abc) = \partial_1(\bar{\partial}_1(ab)c+ab\bar{\partial}_1c)=\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(ab)c
\end{equation}
But also:
\begin{equation}
\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(abc) = \partial_1(\bar{\partial}_1(ac)b+ac\bar{\partial}_1b)=\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(ac)b
\end{equation}
Which would give:
\begin{equation}
\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(abc) = \frac{1}{2}\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(ab)c + \frac{1}{2}\partial_1\bar{\partial}_1(ac)b
\end{equation}
Right? My problem is the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$, which in my reference does not show up. Any reason why it should not be there?
